# VBA to copy and past in two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy all the data and paste it in  new workbook. With the below coding, I am able to paste all the values but it is creating two workbooks and pasting the data in one workbook.

I want to create only one new workbook and past the data. Not sure as to what went wrong.

```
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
wkb(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Copy` method has a different meaning when applied to a Worksheet and when applied to a Range:

- The [Copy method of a Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel) creates a copy of the sheet; in the absence of any parameter, the copy is placed in a new workbook.
- The [Copy method of a Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-copy-method-excel) puts a copy of the Range on the clipboard, from where you can then Paste it somewhere else.

So in your case, the statement

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy
```

already makes a copy the Worksheet into a new workbook.

If you want to create the new workbook explicitly then you should copy the used range to the clipboard:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Copy
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it is creating only one workbook but past function is not working. It copy the data but not pasting the same in new workbook.

Comment: On Error Resume Next
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Copy
wkb(1).Cells("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
On Error GoTo 0

Comment: @GausShaikh: `.Cells(1,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer, but let me do it instead of yourself:

```
On Error Resume Next 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy 
    Dim wkb As Workbook 
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Add 
    wkb(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
    On Error GoTo 0
```

.